# Give variable parameter list to a called function in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I have a function with a printf-like variable parameter list that I call for example with:

```
debugMsg(__FILE__, __LINE__, "failed with var %s = %d\n", var, val);
```

Now I need a wrapper function for this, e.g.:

```
void debugMsgWrapper(const char* FileName, int LineNo, const char* FmtStr, ...)
{
    // do some other things
    DebugMsg(FileName, LineNo, FmtStr, ...);
}
```

Of course this doesn't work with the parameter list specified as `...` but I don't have any idea how to copy the parameter list to the called function. I had a look at
`void va_copy(va_list dest, va_list src);`
but could not find how to use it.

How can I give the variable parameter list to the called function?

Comment: The key part of the answer from that post: "*You cannot pass the variadic arguments to a variadic function. Instead, you must call a function that takes a va_list as argument.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-write `debugMsg` so that it takes a `va_list` instead of a variable number of arguments.  Here's how you'd do it:

```c
void
debugMsg(const char *FileName, int LineNo, const char *FmtStr, va_list args);

void
debugMsgWrapper(const char *FileName, int LineNo, const char *FmtStr, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    // do some other things
    va_start(args, FmtStr); // Make args start after FmtStr;
    debugMsg(FileName, LineNo, FmtStr, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

You can then, in `debugMsg`, repeatedly pull arguments from `args` via `va_arg`:

```c
int n;
const char *string;

n = va_arg(args, int);
string = va_args(args, char*);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) Isn't there a typo with `char char *FmtStr`? Shouldn't it be `const char *FmtStr`?